# mprotect PROT_EXEC on noexec partition

Tags: linux, kernel, mmap, mmu

I tried mmap-ing (more specifically dlopen fails on mmap) a file from disk partition that was mounted with the noexec flag and it resulted in

> failed to map segment from shared object

How does the kernel know once the file is mapped to memory if it's a noexec partition. I couldn't find the code in the kernel source that checks this condition.

I'm using:**Linux version 5.7.11-1-default (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 10.1.1 20200625 [revision c91e43e9363bd119a695d64505f96539fa451bf2] (SUSE Linux), GNU ld (GNU Binutils; openSUSE Tumbleweed) 2.34.0.20200325-1) #1 SMP Wed Jul 29 09:32:21 UTC 2020 (5015994)**

Comment: At least with some 4.x sources, do these routines help?  do_mmap() and path_noexec()

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you :)

Comment: OK, thought so; I'll extend the info in the answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `mmap()` request can lead to the routine `do_mmap()` which conditionally calls `path_noexec()`; `PROT_EXEC` may be enabled or skipped based on a mount flag `MNT_NOEXEC`